# How to get the first term for the current taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm using the following code to display the term for a specified taxonomy:

```
$terms = get_terms( "book_review" );
$category = $terms[0]->name;
```

However I want to display the term for whatever the currently displayed taxonomy is, rather than specifying a particular taxonomy. Basically what I'm wanting is a way to replicate the functionality of get_the_category, but for the current taxonomy instead of the current category. I'm trying to display this on a single custom post type page (single-custom_post_type_name.php)

Comment: What context? The taxonomy page *(URL=`/your-taxonomy/your-term/`)*, or somewhere else?

Comment: I updated the question with the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use `get_queried_object` to get the term name.

```
<?php if( is_tax() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $title= $term->name;
       
}  ?>
```

To display: `<?php echo $title; ?>`

If your on a taxonomy archive page you can use:

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
```

Then to display the term: `<?php echo $term->name; ?>`

***T[he following properties are available for the $term object](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy):***

- term_id
- name
- slug
- term_group
- term_taxonomy_id
- taxonomy
- description
- parent
  -count